# css key-frames animating dynamic height

Tags: css

Hello I have the following css for my sub-menus.It is used in order to open them when the page loads.It works great, however I noticed that if at the end state of the animation I set `height:auto;` then the animation is not being executed.This is an issue for me because in my site I have many sub-menus with n amount of children in them so I must populate the height of the sub-menu dynamically. Is it possible ?

```
   @-moz-keyframes slidemenu {
        0% {
            height: 0px;
        }
        100% {
            height: 90px;
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes slidemenu {
        0% {
            height: 0px;
        }
        100% {
            height: 90px;
        }
    }

    #side-menu > li.active > ul.sub-menu{
        -moz-animation-delay:0.5s;
        -moz-animation-name: slidemenu;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

        -webkit-animation-delay:0.5s;
        -webkit-animation-name: slidemenu;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
```

PS: I'm interested in a pure css solution.

Comment: Can you put together a fiddle and include your html in the question?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xv2BK/ this demonstrates the problem I've set the 100% state of the animation to height auto in order to replicate the issue

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of animating `height`, try animating `transform: translateY()` as follows (you will get a true sliding effect):

```
@keyframes slideDown{
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: But this wouldn't push elements underneath down as it expands.

Answer (score 1):

```
@keyframes pageLoadSubnavDropdown {
    0% {
        max-height: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        max-height: 300px;
    }
}
```

This worked for me but there is still a guessing game as the max-height has to still be over what the max height of all the elements would be. The higher the second number the faster the animation travels no matter how many elements are in the dropdown.

This would be a good fix for a specific range of elements, not so much a fully dynamic range of elements.

Comment: This is generally the best available non-JS solution. However, it would be simpler to use the basic CSS `transition: max-height 0.5s` instead of writing a keyframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work as well

```
#slide-menu {
    background: primary;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-animation: slideDown 3s;
}

//try to declare the keyframes after the #slide-menu
@keyframes slideDown {
    from {
      transform: translateY(-100%);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      transform: translateY(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

you can change the `background: primary` to any color depends on what you want, example `background: white`